# Android Studio BottomSheetFragment.show error

Tags: java, android

Am trying to work with a bottom sheet in an activity that has a map. However

```
public void showBottomSheetDialogFragment() {
       BottomSheetDetailsFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetDetailsFragment();

//This line shows an error in android studio
        bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
    }
```

and my BottomSheet Fragment

```
public class BottomSheetDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

   public BottomSheetDetailsFragment() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_details, container, false);
   }


}
```

Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Please show the error printed in the LogCat

Comment: Build fails with **error: cannot find symbol
        bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
                           ^
  symbol:   method show(FragmentManager,String)
  location: variable bottomSheetFragment of type BottomSheetDetailsFragment**

Comment: Sorry but why you extend from `Fragment`, you need to extend from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: Wow thanks. That fixed it :)